# apache mime4j maven dependency for 0.7.2

Tags: apache, maven

Trying to use the Apache Mime4J dependency for Version 0.7.2 like this:

```xml
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>org.apache.james</id>
    <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.james</groupId>
  <artifactId>apache-mime4j</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I got an error message that the dependency could not be downloaded.
After checking that
http://uk.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/james/apache-mime4j/0.7.2/apache-mime4j-0.7.2.jar
indeed does not exist
but http://uk.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/james/apache-mime4j/0.7.2/
had .bin.tar.gz files I worked around the problem using:

```or-tag-here
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.james</groupId>
   <artifactId>apache-mime4j</artifactId>
   <version>0.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This will therefore not reference the more current 0.7.2 release.

This is my "set of questions":

- Why does the 0.7.2 release not contain a Jar file?
- How should I reference the dependency to get the latest Jar?
- Do I need it anyway?
- What differences are there between the 0.7.2 and the
  0.6.1 release?

Comment: http://uk.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/james/apache-mime4j-core/0.7.2/ has one of the necessary jars as per the changelog mentioned in the edited answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Question 1: Why an artifact might not exist**

According to the changelog there has been some refactoring going on to split the functionality into the three parts: core,dom and storage.

**Question 2: How to get the latest artifact**

modify the dependencies to:

```xml
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.james</groupId>
   <artifactId>apache-mime4j-core</artifactId>
   <version>0.7.2</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.james</groupId>
   <artifactId>apache-mime4j-dom</artifactId>
   <version>0.7.2</version>
 </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.james</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache-mime4j-storage</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.2</version>
  </dependency>
```

**Question 3: Do I need it?**

if you'd like to use the improved DOM API: yes. You will need to modify your
import statements and can not use new Message() any more. Use

```java
MessageServiceFactory.newInstance().newMessageBuilder().newMessage();
```

instead. The multipart.getBodyParts() function has also changed and returns an Entity now.
There is no isMimeType() for the Entity. You might want to use getMimeType() instead.

**Question 4: What changed between versions?**

See [the change log between 0.7.2 and 0.6.1.](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/james/mime4j/trunk/RELEASE_NOTES.txt)

Comment: January 2012 - Apache James Mime4j 0.7.2 released

thanx for the quick shot. This is what I found regarding the changes so far "The Java Apache Mail Enterprise Server (a.k.a. Apache James) Project is happy to announce the release of version 0.7.2 of Apache James Mime4j library. ..."

Comment: Not sure I follow, did my answer help you?

Comment: you might want to edit your answer a bit based on the 0.7 changelog - it looks like the main mime4jar has been split.

Comment: Perfect! I agree that it looks much better :)