# Example of parser using Mime4j 0.7.2 version

Tags: java, parsing, smtp, eml, mime4j

I've a lot of .eml files and need to parse them. I'm using mime4j version 0.6.1 and wanna to update to version 0.7.2, but cannot find any good sample.
 I read post [apache mime4j maven dependency for 0.7.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070543/apache-mime4j-maven-dependency-for-0-7-2/15070696#15070696) and it helped me to get right maven dependency. But it's still a lot of problems with new methods. For example in version 6 class `Multipart` got method `getBodyParts` and return `List<BodyPart>`, and now it returs `List<Entity>`. 
 
Does anyone have good example how to parse SMTP (eml) email with mime4j 0.7.2?

Comment: What about https://james.apache.org/mime4j/samples.html ? It should have fresh samples in distribution pack.

Comment: Of cause I saw this. If you so smart please give me example. How you convert Entity to BodyPart, because I got java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException